# Python : Convert 2D numpy array to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array like below, which I would like to store in a pandas column. I'm unable to find relevant example any where upon search. Please help.Thanks!

```
#2D array
[[0,2],[2,3]]

#Expected output is pandas dataframe with single column :
[0,2]
[2,3]
```

Comment: `pd.Series(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
a = np.array([[0,2],[2,3]])
s = pd.Series(a.tolist())
print (s)
0    [0, 2]
1    [2, 3]
dtype: object
```

EDIT: For avoid lists use:

```
a = np.array([[0,2],[2,3]])
s = pd.Series(list(a))
print (s)
0    [0, 2]
1    [2, 3]
dtype: object

print (s.apply(type))
0    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1    <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
dtype: object
```

Comment: But how to do this if I want the elemnts to remain numpy arrays, not python lists?

Comment: @Toby - added better simplier solution.